# How to train musculation during a fasting period?

Tags: diet, muscle, strength-training, gym

I've just finished my first musculation session. But I am a little bit affraid about my diet in a futur period, In 2 months, I'll not be able to eat till night during one month, so no breakfast, no lunch and dinner will be at about 22:00 (night).

I am aware that it is not good, specially in period of bulk, but how to train, what to eat in this month ? Should I eat and train more now and make this special month to be as if it is a cut period ?

Comment: Might find this interesting https://stronglifts.com/ramadan-weight-lifting-training-build-muscle-lose-fat/

Comment: Related https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/34114/preserve-muscles-while-fasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, until you begin fasting, you should continue to train as usual and eat as much as you can.  Put on extra bodyfat to help fuel you through the fast.

During your fasting period, eat as much as you can when you can (that is, after dark).  Reduce your training volume but do one heavy set of each exercise instead of multiple sets; this way, you will bias your body toward preserving strength without exceeding your reduced recovery capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

But there are many believers in fasted training, where you have your first meal of the day  after you train.

Perhaps train a bit later in the day, and make sure you have a calorie surplus on the days you train.